# Invalid value for key 'authentication'

Tags: json, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have a .NET Core 3.0 app where am trying to connect to a Azure SQL database using EF Core and Active directory integrated authentication.
I have verified that I have access to this database from my machine as I can connect to it just fine using SQL server management studio and 'Azure Active Directory-Integrated' authentication.

However, when I try to read data in my app (using EF Core), I always get a System.Argument exception with the following statement:

**Invalid value for key 'authentication'**

Exception details point to the Db connection string.

So, here is my connection string from my dev appsettings.json file:

> "ConnectionStrings": {
> "MCDB": "Server=tcp:dev-media-center-sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial
> Catalog=MediaCenter;Persist Security Info=False;User
> ID={my User ID};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;"   },

I have tried hard coding the connection string directly in my code, thinking that there might be a problem with my JSON but I still get the same exception.

Is "Active Directory Integrated" not a valid value for the 'Authentication' keyword? If not, what is it then? I have already tried "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated" (with no spaces) and /"Active Directory Integrated"/ (escaping double quotes) but to no avail.

Comment: Where do you run your app? Is it in Azure? Is using Managed Identities an option?

Comment: App was run locally

Answer (score 22):

If you're using EF Core with the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` package, then be aware of this tip from the [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) page on the EF Core Database provider:

> The Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package ships more frequently than the EF
> Core provider. If you would like to take advantage of new features and
> bug fixes, you can add a direct package reference to the latest
> version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.

That being said, the fix is to add the package to your project:

[image: cropped screenshot showing the "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient NuGet" package selected for installation in a user's Solution file in Visual Studio.]

Comment: How do you know that this feature need newer version of SqlClient?

Comment: I have the same error when I choose connection string with AAD userId and password. I have installed SqlClient 3.0.1

Comment: Anyone know what the minimum version of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is that works with this authentication mode?

Comment: Yes, this just worked.

Comment: This worked for me.  I didn't even notice that SqlClient was not referenced as a package.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading to the latest version of `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I saw that I was referring to **System.Data.SqlClient** for DB connectivity in my legacy application. I replaced it with **using  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient** and it resolved the exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same problem discussed in relation to a newer .NET Core version, which was answered as currently unsupported in that version, however I have added a comment where I note that it now works - see [EF Core 3.1 using Authentication=Active Directory Integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166339/ef-core-3-1-using-authentication-active-directory-integrated/64072510#64072510)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity" and be sure to set the User ID to the Object(principal)ID of the identity.

Example:

```
Data Source=dev-westeurope-001.database.windows.net;
     Initial Catalog=dev-westeurope-001;
     Authentication=Active Directory Managed Identity;
     User ID=[PrincipalId];
     TrustServerCertificate=True;
```

Answer (score -3):

If your only option for connecting to the Azure SQL Database is through Active Directory authentication, and your ADO.NET SqlConnection object is having problems trying to recognize the "Active Directory Integrated" value as the Authentication, you can still use the "Active Directory Password" value if you know the credentials of the user you're using to try to connect to the database. The connection string will be something like this:

```
"Server=tcp:yourservername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasename;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Password";"
```

That worked for me.