# How can i configure Nhibernate to use Azure Managed Identity when logging into Azure database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, azure-managed-identity

I am using managed identity to login to Azure database. Most connections are done through Nhibernate. When i call the following

```
 FluentConfiguration fluent;
            fluent = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                        .ConnectionString(c => c
                            .Is(connstring))
                )
```

The connString is

```
string ConnectionString =  @"Server=demo- 
server.database.windows.net,1433;Authentication=Active Directory Default; 
Encrypt=True;Database=DEMO";
```

It gives an error:

```
FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. 

Invalid Value for key 'authentication'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: might be this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/69109716/671619

Comment: tried these suggestions ,looks like they are for Entity Framework, im using Nhibernate. They didnt seem to work. Is there a newer version of Nhibernate that supports Managed Identity ?

Comment: it is about the driver used. It is different to configure in NHibernate but should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver` driver (available since NHibernate v5.3+). And make sure you are referencing [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) v3+ version.

Your Fluent database configuration should look something like:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
            .Driver<MicrosoftDataSqlClientDriver>()
            .ConnectionString(connectionString)
    )
```

Comment: This works if i run from VS under my identity which is SQL Server admin, but the app service is called TestAppMI and after creating an identity there is a System assigned managed identity created as TestAppMI  with an Object Principal ID. I have given this id access to the db but it gives error  System.BadImageFormatException · Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Identity.Client, Version=4.39.0.0,  Although I have selected the latest versions in all . Any ideas on this ?

Comment: Do you have explicit `Microsoft.Identity.Client` project reference in your project? Try removing it or using 4.39.0 version.

Comment: Also read this: https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/763

Comment: If i remove   Microsoft.Identity.Client from the project I get then get an error "Invalid value for key 'authentication"

Comment: @Jennifer --- Did you resolve this issue yet?